# Resetting OpenGL extension pointers in Windows API

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

Some time ago I started working on OpenGL(3.3) renderer for MFC program.Everything was fine till I decided to run some OpenGL debugging tools to see if I have some silent errors.I used 
[gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/) .Running  gDebug program analyzing  tool I immediately started getting errors of the following type:

**Debug String: Detected error: The debugged process asked for an extension function pointer (glGenBuffers) from one render context, but called this function pointer in another render context (context #2)**

In fact every GLEW method gets this error.Now I started looking for a problem in forums and also on MSDN and I found some people mention that in Windows environment some GLEW methods pointers should be redefined.Also I stumbled upon [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/opengltutorialsbyaks/introduction-to-opengl-3-2---tutorial-01) which shows how pretty every GLEW method is redefined using Windows OpenGL methods like these:

```
void CGLRenderer::InitAPI()
{
  // Program
  glCreateProgram = (PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glCreateProgram");
  glDeleteProgram = (PFNGLDELETEPROGRAMPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glDeleteProgram");
  glUseProgram = (PFNGLUSEPROGRAMPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glUseProgram");
  ...
  ....
```

My OpenGL context set-up looks like this:

```
   bool OpenGLMain::create30Context(HDC device_context){
//this->hwnd=hwnd;


hdc=device_context;//GetDC(hwnd);

hdcGlobal=&hdc;


   PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR kPFD;
   memset(&kPFD,0,sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
   kPFD.nSize=sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
   kPFD.nVersion=1;
   kPFD.dwFlags=
   PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW|
   PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL|
   PFD_GENERIC_ACCELERATED|
   PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
   kPFD.iPixelType=PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
   kPFD.cColorBits=32;
   kPFD.cDepthBits=32;
   kPFD.cStencilBits=8;
   kPFD.iLayerType=PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

   int iPixelFormat=ChoosePixelFormat(hdc,&kPFD);
   if(iPixelFormat==0){
 //  ReleaseDC(window,gs_hWindowDC);
   return false;
   }
  BOOL bSuccess=SetPixelFormat(hdc,iPixelFormat,&kPFD);
  if(!bSuccess){
  // ReleaseDC(window,gs_hWindowDC);
   return false;
   }

   /////////init opengl context

  HGLRC tempOpenGLContext=wglCreateContext(hdc);/////Openggl 2.1
  wglMakeCurrent(hdc,tempOpenGLContext);////male openGL 2.1 context current and active
  GLenum error =glewInit();

  if(error!=GLEW_OK){
   return false;
  }
   /////////context setup///////
   int attributes[]={
   WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB,3,
   WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB,2,
   WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB,WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,0


                    };


   if(wglewIsSupported("WGL_ARB_create_context")==1){

   hrc=wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hdc,NULL,attributes);///create OpenGL 3x context based on the supplied attributes
   wglMakeCurrent(NULL,NULL);//remove temp context
   wglDeleteContext(tempOpenGLContext);
   wglMakeCurrent(hdc,hrc);


  }else{
   hrc=tempOpenGLContext;////if no support for OGL 3x detected roll back to 2.0
  }
   /////////version check///////////////
   int glVersion[2]={-1,-1};
   glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION,&glVersion[0]);
   glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION,&glVersion[1]);

     std::cout<<"Using openGL"<<glVersion[0]<<"."<<glVersion[1]<<
     std::endl;     
 OutputDebugString(L"Using OPENGL version:"+glVersion[0]);

return true;
  }
```

Now I am really confused at this point because in fact the program runs fine inside VisualStudio without redefining all these GLEW methods.But it shows the empty screen (no geometry) if I run the executable directly.Also in all the other examples and tutorials I have ever read it had never been mentioned that one has to reset pointers on GLEW API methods.So my question is if anybody can point out to the right way to integrate OpenGL 3.3 in Windows API because it seems that there are many ways doing it.

Comment: Try calling glewInit again after you create and make current your  second context.

Comment: That was a nice hint,now I am getting far less errors.In fact only 2 now: for glGenVertexArrays and glBindVertexArra

Comment: For some reason, if I set `glewExperimental` to true prior to calling `glewInit`, gDEBugger does not complain about the function pointers being from a different context. I don't even have to call `glewInit` again for the new context. I have no idea if this works consistently across different systems, but it is certainly worth a try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function pointers you get are based on the *current context*. That is, it is entirely possible for you to get different function pointers for different OpenGL contexts. gDEBugger is telling you that it has detected that you're using function pointers with a different context from the one used to acquire them. Which is not guaranteed to work.

That being said, it generally will work. It won't work if the two contexts aren't from the same vendor (and probably for the same GPU or SLI/CrossFire GPU setup). But if they are, it should be fine.

GLEW, as I understand it, doesn't have a way to accommodate two different contexts that *don't* use the same function pointers. You would have to call `glewInit` every time you changed contexts.

Comment: It seems you are right ,I added the glewInit() call after I initiate the second (3.3) context.But still getting errors from the type I wrote above for glGenVertexArrays and glBindVertexArray.But the rest are gone now.

Comment: Do I understand correctly from your signature that Nicol Bolas is aka  Alfonse Reinheart ? :)  Could you also explain why in gDEBugger I see a blank viewport while in VS it renders my stuff ok ?

Comment: @MichaelIV: I don't use gDEBugger. All I can say is how contexts and functions interact.

Comment: @MichaelIV: It's not just about context creation, but also context switching. You must add a `glewInit` after every call to wglMakeCurrent / wglMakeContextCurrent.

Comment: @datenwolf ,that is what I do now ,and still getting 2 errors for glGenVertexArrays and glBindVertexArray

Comment: On an Ubuntu VM (in VirtualBox), calls like `glVertex3f` seem to work, but like `glGetIntegerv` do nothing. So, it is plausible that this could be due to using function pointers from a different context?